# Themeing sitemap for drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, sitemap, drupal-theming

There was a nice way of themeing the output of Taxonomy pages in drupal 7 that I stumbled across using the method below 
(template.php)

```
function kestrel_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
    if ( isset($variables['content']['system_main']['term_heading']) )
    {
        $variables['template_files'][] = 'taxonomy_term';
    }//end if
    if(isset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['no_content']))
    {
        unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['no_content']);
    }//end if
}//end function
```

And then create a taxonomy_term.tpl.php file. Nice and simple.

Is there a similarly easy way of being able to create a .tpl file to theme the output of the /sitemap page?